# Changing default browser for emacs, Debian insists on using Firefox

Tags: emacs, browser, settings

In the emacs' .emacs:

`'(browse-url-browser-function (quote browse-url-default-browser))`

I have restarted the system after setting Opera as default browser.
When I run:

`update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser`

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative gnome-www-browser (providing /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/firefox-esr            70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/iceweasel              70        manual mode
* 4            /usr/bin/opera                  120       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

and

`update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`

```
    There are 6 choices for the alternative x-www-browser (providing/usr/bin/x-www-browser).

  Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode

  1            /usr/bin/firefox-esr            70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/iceweasel              70        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/konqueror              30        manual mode
* 5            /usr/bin/opera                  120       manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/qupzilla               80        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

When I click on a .html file directly, it's opened using Opera.

`cat ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=FoxitReader.desktop
application/ppdf=FoxitReader.desktop
```

However, emacs insists on opening files with firefox. Where is it taking this setting from?

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
          browse-url-generic-program "opera")
```